# how to: prices including taxes based on customer location

Tags: magento-1.8, tax, magento-community

I would like to display products with prices including taxes based on customer location. my idea is to display those prices based on customer geolocation even if the customer is not logged and never change to another store.

@FabianBlechschmidt wrote: the customer entity doesn't have a country, the customer has an address, which has a country and all taxes calculation are done with that information.

does anyone know a way to pass that information in order to display prices including taxes for a particular country, even if a customer is not logged. ideas or plugin welcome. brgds!

Comment: Yes, enterprise Net-A-Porter style real-time COGS & DDP/Margin calculations based on multi-country. Magento does not work with multi-country single-tld, you need realtime dynamic pricing. It is something only the $multi-million companies have with other platforms. True, we license it for CE/EE which does the same but the environment is incredibly complex from having its own hosting architecture to special coding and pricing calculations and is a closed environment based on revenue share or $10s thousands for onsite. It is the domain of the multi-nationals and they want to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to get the language from the Accept-Language header and the IP address. based on this information you can guess where the customer is and then open a popup or notice to inform the customer and give him the choice to change this. Then you add this information to the quote and your problem should be solved.

```
// get addresses and set country
Mage::getSingletion('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->setCountryId('DE')->save();
Mage::getSingletion('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('DE')->save();
```

maybe there is no address yet, then you have to create them and set them.

Comment: thanks @Fabian-blechschmidt, when you wrote: "Then you add this information to the quote and your problem should be solved." my main doubt is: magento use cookie information to create the sales quote including taxes (eg: cookie=US for USA) or is always taking the information directly from the address table as you wrote?. i dont know where to store or how to store that info at the platform to perform calculations. brgds!

Comment: updated the answer, hopefully this is enough.