# Customer´s IP recognization without registration or logging in

Tags: vat

I´m looking for Magento extension which recognizes the customer´s IP (user´s country) and based on that, shows (without registration/logging in/checking out) the individual prices with VAT (EU-customer) or without VAT (non EU-customer).

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14699/how-to-prices-including-taxes-based-on-customer-location

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found any specific Extension by your need.

If you want to develop it by yourself, following process would definitely help you:

- Create a custom module for getting Customer COUNTRY by IP address. This following function would help you to get IP address.
  `Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();`
- Then create two Tax Rules based on either Customer TAX class, or, Tax Zones